# Add dashboard widget to page created with add_menu_page()?

Tags: dashboard, add-menu-page

I've created a standard page with a top level menu using add_menu_page() and I want to turn that page into a bespoke dashboard, ie to have a number of boxes like the dashboard widgets using something like wp_add_dashboard_widget(). I cannot find any documentation that even suggests this is possible and I've looked into creating dashboards widgets and then doing something like

```
global $wp_meta_boxes;
$my_widget = $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['example_dashboard_widget'];
unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['example_dashboard_widget']);
$wp_meta_boxes[$my_dashboard]['normal']['core']['example_dashboard_widget'] = $my_widget;
```

where $my_dashboard has variously been a $hook from $hook=add_menu_page() and the page slug etc, but it hasn't worked. As you can tell, I'm shooting in the dark here but this functionality would be *very* useful to me. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Edit: I've found the answer to my own question here

http://www.code-styling.de/english/how-to-use-wordpress-metaboxes-at-own-plugins

Comment: Dashboard widgets only go on the dashboard. You can't put 'em on any other pages, as far as I know.

Comment: I'm going to answer my own question... I finally found this and it works for what I need, with soem amendments :-)

http://www.code-styling.de/english/how-to-use-wordpress-metaboxes-at-own-plugins

Answer (score 1):

I've edited my question to include the fact that I've found the answer to my own question here

http://www.code-styling.de/english/how-to-use-wordpress-metaboxes-at-own-plugins

in case anyone finds the question while searching for a similar solution. The two column variation he includes in his solution no longer seems to work but is a simple thing to override.

Answer (score 0):

Add metaboxes, dashboard widgets are for the dashboard only!

Comment: yeah, that's what the article lead me to. I am effectively treating them as dashboard widgets (as far as I can see, dashboard widgets are a special case of metaboxes) but constructing them as metaboxes

Comment: Have you looked into the function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_dashboard_widget